# GWT Themes/Templates

Tags: css, gwt

I'm developing an application using GWT. Though GWT is a JAVA based medium, the look and feel could only be enriched via CSS. I was wondering if there is some site, where I could download CSS that could make my app look better. Also I was thinking if GWT supports templates/themes unlike Drupal/Joomla. If it does support,is there some place where I could make use of existing templates? Being a developer, I feel the application is not appealing to the user. For instance, I'm using TabLayoutPanel to imitate the menus. But, they doesn't actually look like a menubar. Also the entire application would take only a little amount of screen space. I want the application to fill the entire screen size. Is there any way to solve the above problems??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just out of curiosity why you are not using GWT's MenuBar class? You can write your own CSS for that as you want by overriding  .gwt-MenuBar etc. See here http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MenuBar.html

Comment: Menu is a good option. Can you please provide some examples for menuhandlers?

Answer (score 2):

Like TxANG mentioned, you can use the theme generator. Working demo here http://gwt-theme-generator.appspot.com/
For full screen (all available browser space), use DockLayoutPanel

Answer (score 1):

Im afraid there is no template/theme like in php because there is no predefined skeleton pages (in fact, there is no usual "pages"). All styling have to be done through CSS. If you want to generate a new CSS using different colors, there is a [generator page](http://works.sen-sei.in/gtg/) that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for your second question - Use RootLayoutPanel instead of RootPanel. And then add DockLayoutPanel to it. The center panel of the DocLayoutPanel occupies all available space in the browser.

Answer (score -1):

Try **Vaadin** :)

http://vaadin.com/home

Showcase : http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler

Hope you like the look and feel, this framework build over GWT. You can extend the native GWT classes.

Comment: Warning, in Vaadin "the largest part of the application logic runs securely on the server" (http://vaadin.com/learn).  GWT can do client-only. If you want client only (keeping your backend options open), stick with GWT.

Comment: Any way to get the theme as CSS without having to use their library?