# Are there any custom GWT skins/themes available?

Tags: gwt

In standard GWT offers like 3 themes (standard, chrome, dark). I was wondering, if there are some downloadable themes like those 3, I couldn't Google anything.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353020/gwt-themes-templates and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962883/gwt-2-0-themes. These were results 2 and 3 when I googled GWT themes...

Answer (score 0):

There is a GWT theme generator: http://gwt-theme-generator.appspot.com/